# Make difference between inherited classes

Tags: java, extends

I have 3 class and, first is Person :

```
public class Person {    
    Person() {

    }
}
```

Second is Engineer that extends of Person

```
public class Engineer extends Person { 
    Engineer() {

    } 
}
```

and another extends of Person

```
public class Doctor extends Person {
    Doctor() {

    } 
}
```

Last one is Work that take in constructor an object Person

```
public class Work {
    Work(Person p) {
    //how to insure that p is Engineer ?
    }
}
```

How to detect that an object p is Engeneer and not from another class ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `instanceof` keyword for checking the type of an object. It works like this

```
if(p instanceof Engineer) {
   // do Engineer stuff
} else {
   // not an Engineer object
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check it with the following:

```
if (p instanceof Engineer)
```

or

```
if (p.getClass() == Engineer.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like:

```
if (p.getClass() == Engineer.class) {
    //Is engineer
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Work {

    // ensure only Engineer can pass in
    Work(Engineer p) {

    }
}
```

or using `instanceof` keyword

> The `instanceof` operator compares an object to a specified type. You
>   can use it to test if an object is an instance of a class, an instance
>   of a subclass, or an instance of a class that implements a particular
>   interface.

```
public class Work {

    Work(Person p) {
        // make sure p is type of Engineer
        if(p instanceof Engineer) {
            // dowork
            Engineer e = (Engineer) p;
        } else {
            // not engineer or p is null
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p.getClass()
```

(and from there, `.getName()`)

or the operator `instanceof` (note, a Doctor and an Engineer will be return `instanceOf Person` as true; check for the more specific class)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to do this.

```
Work(Engineer p) {
    // p is an Engineer
}
```

or

```
Work(Person p) {
    p.doWork(); // calls the appropriate work methopd for any person.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use instanceof keyword like

```
if(p instanceof Engineer) {
    // do something
}

if(p instanceof Doctor) {
    // do something
}
```

but this is not right way,
you should have Enginner's behavior(method) in Engineer's class and Doctor's behavior in Doctor class.

See Peter's answer, Runtime polymorphism will detect which method to call automatically.

i.e.

```
class Engineer extends Person {
    // properties
    // methods
    public void doWork() {
        // does engineering work
    }
}

class Doctor extends Person {
    // properties
    // methods
    public void doWork() {
        // does doctor work like check patients, operation or other his task
    }
}

class Work {
    Work(Person p) {
        p.doWork(); // if you pass engineer obj here, Engineer.doWork() is called. And if you pass doctor, Doctor.doWork() is called.
        // You don't need to use instanceof.
    }
}
```

Engineer and Doctor have same method names in above case but in some cases you may need to use instanceof, for e.g. Doctor will have checkPatient() method, Engineer will have some different method name like designEngine(), then you will have to use instanceof.